# Does this pattern for the order of $2$ modulo a power of a prime always hold?

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I know that the order of $2$ modulo $7$ is $3$, the order of $2$ modulo $7^2$ is $3 \cdot 7$, and the order of $2$ modulo $7^3$ is $3 \cdot 7^2$. In general, is it valid to say that if $p$ is a prime and the order of $2$ modulo $p$ is $q$, then the order of $2$ modulo $p^n$ is $q \cdot p^{n-1}$?

Comment: This would mean that $2^n-1$ is never divisible by a non-trivial perfect square when $n$ is prime. I suspect there might be a counterexample, or at least I doubt there is a known proof that this is impossible. So the answer seems likely to be either "no, this is not true," or "we don't know."

Comment: One can quite easily prove a somewhat weaker statement. The [Lifting-the-exponent lemma](Lifting-the-exponent lemma) states for odd primes $p$ with $p \mid x-y$, then $\nu_p(x^n-y^n)=\nu_p(x-y)+\nu_p(n)$. Using this, then if the order of $2$ modulo $p$ is $q$, we get if $\nu_p{2^q-1}=k$ that the order of $2$ modulo $p^n$ is $q$ for $n \le k$, and it's $q\cdot p^{n-k}$ for $n \gt k$. Your question assumes that $k=1$ for all primes but, as [jjagmath's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4811234) indicates, there is at least one counter-example.

Comment: Note that, in my comment above, I accidentally copied the title again instead of the actual link to the Wikipedia article. The correct link is [Lifting-the-exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma). Also, my $\nu_p 2^q-1=k$ should've been $\nu_p(2^q-1)=k$ instead, with this due to me accidentally using brace brackets instead of  round brackets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No:
$$\text{ord}_{1093}(2)=\text{ord}_{1093^2}(2)=364$$

Comment: $p=1093$ and $p=3511$ are the only counterexamples for $p<100000$.

Comment: @lhf Did you check that comparing $\text{ord}_p(2)$ with $\text{ord}_{p^2}(2)$? Because a counterexample could happen when comparing $\text{ord}_{p^n}(2)$ with $\text{ord}_{p^{n+1}}(2)$ for greater values of $n$.

Comment: I only checked whether $ord_{p^2}(2)\ne  p\ ord_p(2)$.

Comment: @jjagmath FYI, please see my question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4811224/order-of-2-modulo-a-power-of-prime#comment10235469_4811224), and the corrections below it, regarding your specific concern.

Comment: An indication that that is all that is known: https://oeis.org/A001220

Comment: Would it suffice to disprove the hypothesis in question that $2^2 \equiv 1\pmod 3$ and $2^{12} \equiv 1\pmod {3^2}$ but $12 \ne 3 \cdot 2$ ?

Comment: @LuckyChouhan No, because the question is asking about the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order), i.e., the *smallest* positive integer power $m$ where $2^m \equiv 1\pmod{3^2}$. Since $2^6=64\equiv 1\pmod{3^2}$, with $6$ being the smallest such power and $6 = 3\times 2$, the hypothesis is not disproven.

Comment: Now I see, I made a huge mistake. Thank you @JohnOmielan :)

Answer (score 0):

With base $10$ instead of $2$ the corresponding minimal counterexample is $p=487$, thus $10^{486}-1$ is divisible by $487^2$.

This has implications for a famous puzzle, the "twin square problem". Identify a number which, when concatenated with itself in base ten, forms a square. For example, $13223140496$ concatenated with itself gives $1322314049613223140496=36363636364^2$.

We can generate infinitely many solutions by the following algorithm:

- Select natural numbers $m,n$ such that $n$ is greater than $3$ and divides $10^m+1$.
- Then applying the Binomial Theorem to $[(10^m+1)-(1)]^n$ shows that $10^{mn}+1$ is divisible by $n^2$.
- Divide out this factor of $n^2$ and multiply by $r^2$, where $r<n<\sqrt{10}r$ to obtain a product with $mn$ digits.
- Concatenating this number with itself then gives a square.

For instance, $m=1$ pairs with $n=11$ to give $(10^{11}+1)×(4^2/11^2)=13223140496$ as the minimal solution, as above. Pairing $m=3$ with $n=7$ gives $21$-digit solutions.

One might suppose that *all* solutions might be generated in this way. And one might be wrong because of that  the $487$ counterexample. We have $487^2|10^{486}-1$ and, as $10$ is not a quadratic residue $\bmod487$, then $487^2|10^{243}+1$ and there are $243$-digit numbers which become squares when twinned. But the binomial theorem-based approach above misses $mn=243$ and so does not identify $10^{243}+1$ as divisible by any square.